# Why is the output always zero?

Tags: c, types, area

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a,b,c,t;
    printf("Get the height of the triangle",a);
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Get the base of the triangle",b);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    t=0.5;
    c=t*(a*b);
    printf("The area of the triangle:%d\n",c);
    scanf("%d",&c);
    return 0;
}
```

After writing the code, compiling, and executing it, no matter the value of `a` and `b` are entered, the answer is always zero.  I wish to know why, and how to correct my error.

Comment: `int t; t = 0.5;` What does that mean in your mind?

Comment: I'm giving the value of t

Comment: OK, but `t` is an integer.

Comment: And what values can `t` hold?

Comment: An `int` is not a floating-point type.  Any floating-point value that is assigned to an `int` will be truncated at the decimal point and lose all digits after the decimal point. So, if the result of the multiplication is `0.xxxxxxxx`, the integer result will be `0`.

Comment: And what do you expect from this? `printf("Get the height of the triangle",a);` I get a compiler warning.

Comment: @FredLarson: That is surprisingly not actually a problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, but it is odd, and it indicates at least a misunderstanding and possibly a false expectation.

Comment: Is it because of the function declaration?

Comment: @EnowNesta - I voted to close as a simple typo because you selected the wrong datatype. I think its a fair beginner question. I don't think it deserved 8 downvotes. A question with 4 answers indicates at least 4 people think its a fair question. Don't let the downvotes detract you.

Answer (score 4):

An `int` cannot hold a floating-point value.  Assigning a floating-point value to an `int` will truncate the value at the decimal point.

When you assign `0.5` to `t`, which is an `int`, it will be set to `0`.  Multiplying anything by `0` results in `0`.

You need to use a floating-point data type, `float` or `double`, when performing your multiplication, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    float c, t;
    printf("Height of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Base of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    t = 0.5f;
    c = t * (a * b);
    printf("The area of the triangle: %f\n", c);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    double c, t;
    printf("Height of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Base of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    t = 0.5;
    c = t * (a * b);
    printf("The area of the triangle: %lf\n", c);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set `t=0.5;`, you set an `int` with a `float`.

The float will be truncated to its integer part, which means here, you get `t=0`.

So when you multiply `t*(a*b)` you do `0*a*b` and get 0.

Use `float t = 0.5` and all should be ok.

Comment: Also scanf should be using %f instead of %d since %d is for integers and %f is for floats.

Comment: When I replace %d by %f, the answer of the execution give me 0

Answer (score -1):

The data type of your 't' variable is int. When you assign a float value to variable 't' it gets truncated in your case it will be truncated to 0. In order to get the correct result that your expecting change your t variables data type from int to float

Comment: to be precise, the variable gets **truncated**, not **rounded**.

Comment: that's correct i agree

Comment: To be pedantic, you can't "assign a float to `t`", since assignment expressions of fundamental type are homogeneous only in C++. The operand is converted *before* the assignment. It's that conversion that really comes into play here.